# Fit Toolbar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have the following issue with my app, specifically with the Action Bar:

[image]

and the ID (indicated with the red rectangle) but since the size of the Action Bar nor the icons contained in cannot be changed due to esthetic reasons, I would like to display a text with the whole number and ID when the users press in the section I've highlighted.

Currently, I'm setting the text like this(delivery var and idDelivery are Strings):

```
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle(delivery);
    ab.setSubtitle("ID:" + idDelivery);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use Tooltip for this and anchor the tooltip to the menuitem. Take a look at this: [Tooltip Library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `MenuItem`s `showAsAction` attribute to `ifRoom`:

```
<item app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        .../>
```

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html):

> Only place this item in the app bar if there is room for it. If there is not room for all the items marked **"ifRoom"**, the items with the lowest orderInCategory values are displayed as actions, and the remaining items are displayed in the overflow menu.

Thus, the title of your `Toolbar` would be given higher priority, and `MenuItem`s would be displayed only when there is enough room for them, otherwise they would be left to be displayed under overflow icon popup menu.