# showAsAction=ifRoom hides the title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a pretty simple menu with one item in it

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnFinishProject"
        android:title="@string/projectend"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         />
</menu>
```

I'm calling this menu in an Activity with this code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.orderdetail_menu, menu);
     return true;
 }
```

In the `onCreate` event of this activity I set the titile programatically with

```
setTitle("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr");
```

This is the result

[image: it hides the title]

It hides the title, instead of the menu item.
Why is this?

Comment: then what you want?

Comment: This looks much alike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152220/fit-toolbar-title) question. Try to remove `withText`.

Comment: i tried that, but does not work either - same result

Comment: add setHasOptionMenu(true) in onCreate

Comment: it' an activity, not a fragment. activities don't have `setHasOptionMenu(true)`

Comment: Hi Thomas, have you got a fix for this issue? I'm having the same problems. Title is going to be very small and menu-item doesn't dissapear on small devices. I'm also setting the title programatically.